# PHP how to set variable value got through ldap?

Tags: php

I'm checking whether the user is admin or not from ldap also i'm getting value from ldap

Part of code is,

```
foreach ($memberOf as $key => $value) {
    $membership = explode(",", $value);
    $member     = explode("=", $membership[0]);
    if (in_array($member[1], $adminGroups)) {
        $is_admin = TRUE;

    } elseif (in_array($member[1], $userGroups)) {
        $is_admin = FALSE;
    }
```

So my question, how i can use this `$is_admin` variable everywhere in my application so that I can hide some buttons depending on whether user is an admin or not etc?

Do I need to set this variable in session?

Comment: Looks like bad pratice what you have there...

Comment: Why don't you add a column to your DB table to define a user as admin or user? that could be far better to use. And yes, you should use session to store the type of user

Comment: `can hide some buttons` you will need to also do checks on every PHP page that allows administrative action, just hiding doesn't do much.

Comment: @ Muhammed Hedayet : Currently i have users data in database but now we dont want to store anything in database everything should come from ldap.

Comment: @ Christian Gärtner : Can you explain in detail ? So that i can improve my code

Answer (score 0):

Use PHP's sessions!

Simply `session_start()` at the top of the files you wish to use sessions in...

assign a session key

```
$_SESSION['is_admin'] = true;
```

then check the key later in different parts of your application...

```
if($_SESSION['is_admin'] === true) { /* do stuff */ }
```

Couple that with a function or class, you can have yourself a nice and easy authentication library.

> https://www.php.net/manual/en/book.session.php

**Edit**:

I've had to use LDAP authentication a bit.. the last thing you want to do is hammer the LDAP server and get your account locked, this is why I suggested sessions. Authenticate once... once authenticated, just use the session from there on out until it expires... then the user simply logs in again.

Answer (score 0):

There are a couple of options:

- Using an session if you want it to persist after a page reload/navigation
- Use a static member in a static class so you can reference it everywhere if do not want persistence